# What is the Python script to set the current frame

Tags: python

I have made a script to generate a game asset in one click ( http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383624-Dark-Blender-(Official-Thread)-optimized-for-sculpting-and-game-asset-creation ). My script save the textures by doing a render and import them with the .0001 number meaning frame 1. If the frame is changed my script is unable to find the texture.0001 so i want to set at the beginning of my Python script the frame to 1.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set the current frame by calling:

<s>`bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 1`</s>

[`bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set)

This will set the scene frame and updates all objects immediately, see the docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set

---

Related: [How to stop Action Constraint giving different results when code is run in text editor vs python console?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/how-to-stop-action-constraint-giving-different-results-when-code-is-run-in-text)

> Use the method frame_set(...) instead. It forces an immediate update of all objects in the scene, including animations (transformation matrices etc. will be calculated)

Comment: `frame_current` should only really be used as a read-only property. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6510/241

Comment: I'm getting "python script fail" when i try this.

DO i need write something else in my script?

Comment: @IvanKartofanov You need to import the bpy module. Just insert the line `import bpy` as the first line of the script.

Comment: in Blender 2.83, this freezes the application, it crashes and shuts down.

Answer (score 3):

(For Blender 2.83+) In order to advance to the next frame, get the frame you're on currently and add one to it. Set that using `frame_set`:

```
currentFrame = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_set(currentFrame + 1)
```

Otherwise replace `currentFrame + 1` with the frame number you want:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_set(10)
```

This assumes you're in the default scene, 'Scene'. In 2.83...

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(10)
```

...still works for whatever scene you happen to be in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain what this does and add more details to your question. Don't just post some random code snippet, explain what it does.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks, edited to add clarity and context

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that's easy to understand

```
C.scene.frame_set(C.scene.frame_current+1)
```