# Script for repeated import and export

Tags: scripting, export, import, stl

I have to create a movie by importing single stl objects, which represent the object at a specific time frame, onto a background and export them to single pngs.
After that i can put them into a video with the sequencer.

My question is, how can i automate (by using a script) the process of importing the stls one after another onto the background and exporting the png after every step?
I am new to python/blender.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5065/86891 Replace the `bpy.ops...` line with `bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(...)` You just need to find out how to change the current frame between 2 imports. Hint : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55638/86891