# Demand Python script keep running until timeline animation stop

Tags: python, animation, scripting, physics

I have a script to run animation which is simulating sewing clothes. Below is a part of my code to add handle and start animation.

```
def sew(body_name, garment_name, export_body):
    body_obj = bpy.data.objects[body_name]
    garment_obj = bpy.data.objects[garment_name]
    s = bpy.context.scene
    s.frame_start = 1
    s.frame_end = 40
    s.frame_current = 1
    def stop_playback(scene):
        if scene.frame_current == 25:
            bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
            after_sew(garment_name, export_body)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(stop_playback)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

While intending to run the sewing animation from frame 1 to frame 25, I want to keep the python execution active so it will run `after_sew()` when the animation is done. When I run the script inside Blender's TextEditor, it does wait until the animation complete, and the `after_sew()` function does run accordingly. However, when I try to run this in background:

```
    blender myblend.blend -b --python sewing.py
```

The script will compile until this `sew()` function, start the animation, but then exit immediately without waiting for the animation reach frame 25, thus `after_sew()` will not run.

Is there any way to make python wait until animation done with an UI-less Blender?

I've found other similar thread talking about animation, but they are mostly about rendering with a camera which  I don't need. What I only need is to export the sewed cloth at frame 25 using the `after_sew()` function.

Comment: Why does the animation need to play. Does script not work if you iteratively set the scene frame?

Comment: How can I do that? Didn't know there is a way to iteratively set the scene frame. And will that work in a UI-less Blender?

Comment: `Scene.frame_set(100)`, yes it will work in headless mode.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem @kelvinhong方 Recently updated: [What is the Python script to set the current frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55638/) Does that answer your question?

Comment: @brockmann Yes, it works perfectly. This really saves me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I don't need handler. Just iteratively change the frames as suggested by @batFINGER and @brockmann

```
def sew(body_name, garment_name, export_body):
    body_obj = bpy.data.objects[body_name]
    garment_obj = bpy.data.objects[garment_name]
    s = bpy.context.scene
    s.frame_start = 1
    s.frame_end = 40
    s.frame_current = 1
    for i in range(2, 26):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
```

And this does work with a headless Blender.